# Проблема с Tomcat на Azure cloud

Tags: java, tomcat, azure

В Azure Cloud поднят Tomcat. В томкэт задеплоен REST сервис (для пользовательских клиентов системы), в котором есть служба, поднимающая сервер-сокет для приема соединений от сервисных клиентов системы и ответа им на запросы. Также сервис может коннектиться к этим самым сервисным клиентам напрямую по IP через те же сокеты. Сервисные клиенты - андроид и пк.

Проблема в том, что при запуске сервиса на локальном Томкэте сервер-сокет прекрасно работает, а при запуске в Азуре - нужный порт недоступен. 
Настроить server.xml в Азуре я не могу, так как при попытке изменить его, Азур выдает ошибку прав доступ. Текущий конфиг коннектора Томкэта в Азуре:

```
<Connector port="${port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="127.0.0.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

Собственно вопрос: можно ли как-то открыть нужный порт в Томкэте в пределах Азура?

Если нет, то какой из вариантов предпочтительней?

1. Вебсокеты
2. Вынести прием коннекта к серверу в REST, а обратный коннект оставить через сокеты
3. еще что-то?

Comment: Погодите, вы как развернули там TomCat? На просто виртуальной машине (IaaS) или на CloudService'e (PaaS)? Почему решили не использовать Azure Website? Там TomCat работает лучше и мороки с администрацией меньше. TomCat можно поднять различными способами и пробема будет решать совершенно разными путями. Может быть это вообще не проблема том-кэта, а настройки файервола машины.

Comment: @Walter TomCat поднят как готовое веб-приложение(Создать -> Интернет+мобильные устройства -> Веб-приложение).
Попробовал создать "Azure Website + SQL" - моя DreamSpark'овская подписка не позволила мне этого сделать :(

Comment: Так и не нашел решения, перешел на вебсокеты.